# Highchairs fill in the inside of the chart on a different background color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and I need to fill in the inside of the chart in a different color.

I’ve tried:

```
chart: {
  renderTo: ‘container’,
  background-color: ‘#ff0000’
},
```

etc…

but this is only changing the background of the whole chart.

Here is a screenshot showing what I need to change.

[image]

How can I do this?

Here's the code too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {


            window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'

                },

                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1,
                    inputDateFormat: '%d-%m-%Y',
                    inputDateParser: function (value) {
                        value = value.split('-');
                        return Date.UTC(
                            parseInt(value[2]),
                            parseInt(value[1]) - 1,
                            parseInt(value[0])
                        );
                    },
                },

                title: {
                    text: ''
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function () {


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'label',
                    data: data,
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                 }}]

            }, function(chart) {

                // apply the date pickers
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
                }, 0)
            });



        // Set the datepicker's date format
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                this.onchange();
                this.onblur();

            }
        });




    });

</script>
```

Comment: You should use area type of your series instead of line type. Then in your area series you can add fillColor parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf6wmr4g/

Comment: Tried that fillColor: 'rgba(200,100,100,0.5)', but it only colored the tidy bottom part of the chart

Comment: SO could you post an image showing how you would like your chart to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the chart type to "area" and specify a fillColor:

```
chart: {
    type: 'area'
}
plotOptions: {
   area: {
      fillColor: 'red'
   }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/dsuLzpqL/

Comment: I've added the code ... where about do I add this code?

Answer (score -1):

Parts of series are called 'zones', you can color them as follows http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.zones

sample code:

```
    series: [{
        data: [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15, 10, 10, 5, 0, -5],
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: '#f7a35c'
        }, {
            value: 10,
            color: '#7cb5ec'
        }, {
            color: '#90ed7d'
        }]
    }]
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/)

Comment: This is only coloring the lines. I need the background..like fillColor: 'rgba(200,100,100,0.5)', does

Comment: use plotbands to color background [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-addplotband/)

Comment: This answer is better suited to situations where you want specific ranges or sections of the chart to be colored vs. the original poster's request for the entire plot area underneath the line to be colored.